# Convex Maximization to convex minimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, maximum-principle

I need your expertise in solving the following problem:

Given a convex set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and a positive (or semi-positive) definite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, we wish to solve the following maximization problem:
$$ \max_{x \in C} \left\| Ax \right\|_2^2$$

This function is convex, hence by Rockafellar's Convex Analysis (specifically Theorem 32.2), the maximum can be achieved at $x^\prime \in \partial(C)$, i.e. a boundary point of $C$.

Is there a way to convert the maximization problem to minimization problem while:

- $C$ is still the set of instances.
- The new function we wish to minimize is convex.

This is speaking only regarding the function:
$$ \left\| Ax\right\|_2^2 $$

If this is not possible, is there a way to convert this function to (I don't that this is possible):
$$ c^Ty,$$
such that $y$ has been constructed from $x \in C$, i.e. we wish to have
$$ c^Ty = \left\| Ax \right\|_2^2.$$

Comment: No, because there can be multiple local maxima, e.g. consider $C=[-1,1]$ in the one-dimensional case.

Comment: So there is no way to convert to minimization problem?
Also we cant convert it to a vector-vector multiplication, right?

Comment: Correct, a convex minimization only has one local minimum.